# Looking at creating a VBA that the user can search for data and be placed into a excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

Looking at the following code and trying to alter it. I want to search for a key phrase on a website i.e "contractor name" and then have the details underneath that phrase copied into my excel spreadsheet.

Code example below, let me know if there's anymore information I can give. I've added my latest changes

```
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub TedEuropaEuData()

'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument

'to refer to the searching
Dim Range, Keyword$, N%, SearchAgain As VbMsgBoxResult

'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:265491-2018:TEXT:EN:HTML&src=0"

'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to TED ..."
    DoEvents
Loop

'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = IE.document

MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

'close down IE and reset status bar
Set IE = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

'clear old data out and put titles in
Cells.Clear

'put heading across the top of row 3
Range("A3").Value = "Company ID"

MsgBox "When finished - click X on the web window to close it "
StartSearch:
N = 0
Keyword = InputBox("Type 'Name and address of the contractor'", "Keyword Is ?")
If Keyword = Empty Then GoTo StartSearch
For Each Keyword In html
    If html Like "*" & Keyword & "*" Then
        MsgBox Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value2

End If
Next Cell
If N = 0 Then MsgBox "Sorry, no " & Keyword & "'s found", , "not Found"
SearchAgain = MsgBox("Another search?", vbYesNo, "More?")
If SearchAgain = vbYes Then GoTo StartSearch


End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry, this is an example i found online. I want to search for a key phrase on a website i.e "contractor name" and then have the details underneath that phrase copied into my excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Since you're 'working on it' I'd much rather see the changes that you've made to it instead and help you work through it :)

Comment: Added my latest update, struggling with a command to write to excel and find text underneath a key phrase.

Comment: to find text under the cell, try `MsgBox Cell.Offset(1,0).Value2`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've change the code around a little. Getting issues with `For Each Cell In html`

Comment: "htlm" is an HTLM document representing the contents of your webpage, not an Excel range. It doesn't make any sense to loop through each cell in it, since it doesn't have any cells.

Comment: @JoshEller actually i'm not so sure, this site makes it look like you might be able to do it https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/

Comment: Dawn, what do you mean by you're "getting issues with" it? what's happening?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 What are you pointing to on that site? Yes of course you can automate reading from a webpage, but HTML documents don't have any Excel cells.

Comment: @JoshEller under "Open URL and Enter Data in Form Using VBA" : `For Each itm In IE.document.all` and Dawn's `html` item is an `ie.document`

Comment: I've added  my update but getting a compile error: For Each control variable must be a variable or object. This is on Ln 50 and highlights keyword. Thanks

Comment: @JoshEller I'm trying to let the user type 'Name and address of the contractor' and have vba search the website. Then get the information that is a few lines under that text and get it into Excel